# SonarQube major isuue raised 'Define and throw a dedicated exception instead of using a generic one.'?

Tags: java, exception, sonarqube

I need to throw RuntimeException for the KeycloakAuthenticationProvider . We are using **SonarQube** tool for code review purpose.

**Here is the code**

```
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception { 
      KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
      auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
 }
```

Now, SonarQube raises an issue for the same , Now what should be replaced to fix the sonar violation.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is the `throws Exception` in your method signature:

```
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
```

SonarQube informs you that instead of the generic `Exception` that is the basis of all exceptions, both checked and unchecked you shoud reference the actual (checked) exception that may be thrown by the methods that you are calling.

Usually, your IDE should already suggest a suitable Exception class.

Comment: Thanks for the response @void but I am not getting suggestions from the IDE.

Comment: Can you check the methods that you are calling (```keycloakAuthenticationProvider()``` and ```authenticationProvider(...)```) if they have a ```throws SomeKindOfExceptionClass``` in their method signature? If yes, that is the exception type you are looking for. Otherwise if it is a checked exception, you can just omit the ```throws Exception``` and try to build the application, you should then see what checked Exception is not checked for.